# RabbitMq Dynamically Add/Remove Queues/Consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, message-queue, task-queue

I have an application that receives messages of three types from multiple users at same time and I am handling it using 3 queues/consumers and 3 exchanges. My problem is that when there are thousands of messages from one user in queues then other users are waiting.

I am looking for a solution to execute jobs of every user in parallel. I can create queues dynamically for every user but that's not a good solution because there will be hundreds of queues and consumers. How can I remove idle consumers/queues automatically. Can I use celery and redis for this problem in any way?

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good idea to use many queues in RabbitMQ. Queue is a single thread on RabbitMQ server.

Your problem is "thousands of msgs from one user will block other users", I think the solution is use [Priority Queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html).

Each user has a counter to record how many messages has been sent in a period time, if this value is large, the messages published by the user will have low priority. So if many messages are waiting in the queue, the messages from other user will be first sent to your consumer jobs. In this situation, you should set a appropriate "prefetch" on consumer's channel.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I cannot set low priority to some of the messages as all messages are equally important. I need to consume all messages in parallel for each user but in a efficient way. Looking for a way to delete idle consumers/Qs.

Comment: @WAnjum It is easy to delete idle queue by using `auto-delete queue`. An `auto-delete queue` is deleted when its last consumer has canceled or when the channel/connection is closed.

Comment: How can I cancel consumer after 30 minutes of idle time?

Comment: @WAnjum There is an queue option `TTL policy`. But it is hard to exactly ensure whether a queue is idle, you can never know a message will be send in the future. If the queue has been deleted, the messages from the user will lost.

Comment: Currently I am thinking about making sets of Qs. First user gets first set (q1,q2..) second get the second set (q3,q4..) and so on until sets are finished and then start from set 1. In this way multiple users can be in parallel. Any drawbacks of this logic?

Comment: @WAnjum Do you have so many messages? One queue can handle up to about 50k messages/s. Why not use multithread workers in consumers.

Comment: Messages are not that many but they are time consuming and I acknowledge only after the complete execution.

Comment: @WAnjum But you can use multithread consumers on a queue. I still can't understand why use so many queues.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting multi-threaded consumers. Are you saying that I should consume each message in separate thread? Isn't this resource intensive

Comment: @WAnjum I mean consumer in a single thread (It is not safety to share channel between threads), multi-workers in multi thread. It is not required to do consume and do work in the same thread.

Comment: Is there a way to kill a consumer if there is no message for long time?

Comment: @WAnjum RabbitMQ doesn't support this. Maybe you should do this in your code with a counter.

Comment: https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.14/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html 
I am using this code as my consumer. I am not sure where I can use counter. In connection method or somewhere else.

Comment: @WAnjum Just store the count in the `ExampleConsumer` and increase it in `on_message`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I managed to make it work by adding timestamp with each queue. When timestamp expires I publish kill message to consumer and it deletes itself and queue is auto deleted.

Answer (score 3):

you have to add more queues in order to scale and to be consistent you can use a hashing distribution.

You can use plugins as https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange or you can do it manually, with more queues you can scale if one node is not enough you can create a cluster (https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) and distribute the load across more nodes.

One consumer for a queue, if you need the sequentiality.

if you don't need the sequentiality you can add more consumers to the same queue, so in this way, you can scale using more queues, more nodes, more consumers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Problem with more queues and consumers is that it requires more resources. Second thing is that I cannot tell how much Qs/Cons I need at startup. As far as hashing is concerned I don't have distribution problem right now. I can distribute messages in different queues based on flags. But the problem is all messages are high priority and I cannot set some to low priority.